# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

Trying to get my first multi-table MySQL database but i've gut an error I just can wrap my head around.  Can someone please suggest an approach before I toss my computer out a window?

### **Setup**

I have two tables:

1. *clients* which has rows: *id, tourbk_id, tourstart, roomtype1, client_name*
2. *tourprices* which has rows: *id, tour_id, tourstart, roomtype, roomprice*

### **Goal**

I'm intending for the following query to look, in the *clients* table for the tour the client wishes to purchase, compare the tour date + tour name + room type in the *client* table, and echo the price.

### **My *fubar* Query**

```
    $tourquery = "SELECT t.roomprice 
         FROM clients c, tourprices t 
         WHERE c.roomtype1 = t.roomtype 
         AND c.tourstart = t.tourstart
         AND c.tourbk_id = t.tour_id"; 
$tourresult = $db->query($tourquery); 

echo '<strong>',"Per room amount:  ",'</strong>'.$tourresult. "";

$tourresult->free();
```

As-is, the result is just an error stating:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string