# Error in echo when use max() in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have to find max value from database. for this purpose i have used max() with where clause but when i echo the result then i get this error.

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in**

i have searched alot and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020298/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-s),, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245473/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-mysqli-could-not-be-converted-to-string-i)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435342/select-max-not-returning-anything-in-php-mysql) and some of others but found nothing helpfull...

**my code is :**

```
include('connection.php');

$qry = "SELECT MAX(week)  FROM reservation WHERE status= 1" ;

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$qry2);


echo $result ;
```

on the same page other query is working fine but this one is not..

**what i want :**

basically i want to get the maximum week number where status is = 1

Comment: You have to fetch the result first `$r = mysqli_fetch_array($result); echo $r[0];`

Comment: you may need to take a quick look at the docs of [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to figure out what's wrong, specially `Return Values` section

Comment: print_r($result)

Comment: where are u fetching the results?

Comment: notice undifined index : qry2

Comment: thnx all ...problem is solved

Comment: @Khan glad we could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT MAX(week) AS max_week reservation WHERE status= 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["max_week"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is corrected code:

```
include('connection.php');

$qry = "SELECT MAX(week) as max_week  FROM reservation WHERE status= 1" ;

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$qry);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['max_week'];
}
```

Comment: There's nothing correct with this code.. The problem here is not the fetching of the query, the query it self is never sent to the db

Comment: because query string defined variable `$qry` but at the time of sending to db it is different variable `$qry2`

Comment: That's not me.. I was correcting your mistake. And why are using a loop for a single result?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it whose question it is.

Comment: @Gaurav this was a mistake ...actual problem was in fetching records any way thanx for help